# how to redirect to another page if condition true

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router, google-cloud-firestore

i want to redirect if user state is loggedIn to true then it redirect to homescreen it show state is change when i login but did'nt redirect to homescreen.

```
`componentDidMount() {
//realtime auth state subscriber
this.auth_unsb = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
    //if logged in
    this.handleUser(user);

    //each time user logs in, subscribe to realtime changes for it's doc
    this.user_unsb = this.firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .onSnapshot(
        doc =>
          //sync user data to store
          (Store.currentUserDoc = doc.data()),
        e => {}
      );
  } //if logged out
  else {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
    //unsubscribing from realtime user do changes
    if (this.user_unsb) this.user_unsb();
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
});
```

}
`

Comment: The code you shared shows that you redirect to `/login` when there is no user signed in, but it doesn't show any redirect to the home screen. Did you forget something like `<Redirect to="/home" />` in there?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect easily you can use the following code :

```
if (your_condition) {
    window.location.href = 'your/path';
}
```

This universal with `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the history object,

```
history.push("/login");
```

or 
in the render method check for `this.user_unsb` value,

```
if(this.user_unsb){
  return <Redirect to="/login" />;
}

// return your component jsx;
```

Hope this can help you!